# Nesting quotes in shell

Tags: linux, shell, python

I want to execute a command which looks like

```
$ sh -c 'exec python -c "print('$1$2MyString')"'
```

with the desired result `'$1$2MyString'`.

However, when I execute the command, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'MysString' is not defined
```

I understand that when I add a third level of quotes, it essentially cuts the command in two parts, and that the shell sees `$1$2MyString` outside quotes and tries to substitute for known values.

If I escape the single quotes,

```
$ sh -c 'exec python -c "print(\'$1$2MyString\')"'
```

I get the following error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Essentially, my question is: is there a way to introduce string literals in the print function above?

Comment: look at how the code highlighting on this website highlights parts of your string: your `'` in front of `$1` ends your shell string. So, you need to \ escape that.

Comment: Escaping the single quotes inside `print` doesn't work either, I get the error `sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: oh, yeah, sorry missed that the outer string was already single-quoted. See Chris' answer! Anyways, it is at least a bit *strange* to `sh -c 'exec python -c 'pythoncode'`, to be honest! Why the `sh` just to run python? Why the `exec`?

Comment: I also need to have access to the PID of the process withing the python code, hence the use of `sh -c` and `exec`, according to https://serverfault.com/questions/205498/how-to-get-pid-of-just-started-process. I did not mention it as it seemed unnecessary for a minimal working example.

Comment: don't quite understand why you'd need `exec` or an extra shell for that, but I'll just believe you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't escape single quotes inside a single quoted string. For example this is an incomplete line:

```
echo 'boy\'s game'    # Wrong!
>
```

However you can abut strings enclosed by different types of quotes:

```
echo "boy's"' game'    # Right
boy's game
```

As a consequence you can quote the quotes, `"'"` etc.:

```
sh -c 'exec python -c "print('"'"'$1$2MyString'"'"')"'
#     ^-. . . . . . . . . . -^   ^-. . . . . -^   ^--^
#                             ^-^              ^-^
```

This outputs `MyString` because the `$1$2` are evaluated by the invocation of `sh`. If you want `$1$2MyString` as a literal you need to ensure it's inside single quotes and protected from the explicit `sh`:

```
sh -c 'exec python -c '"'"'print("$1$2MyString")'"'"
#     ^-. . . . . . .-^   ^-. . . . . . . . . .-^
```

Comment: That leaves off `$1$2` preceding `MyString`. On the other hand, `sh -c 'exec python -c "print("'"'"'"'\$1\$2MyString'"'"'"'")"'` includes `$1$2` as `$1$2MyString`. Of course, perhaps $1 and $2 are supposed to expand positional parameters although that was never indicated......

Comment: Unless there is something going with all of the environments on several OS's which consist of the default in some cases and variations in others, what you have only prints `MyString`, What I have in my comment prints `$1$2MyString` across all of them.

Comment: @NasirRiley that would be wrong then. The `$1$2` are inside double quotes for the explicit `sh` invocation, so should be evaluated by that shell before being passed to python

Comment: Whether it's right or wrong or what should happen, that is what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Quotes never nest (apart from command substitutions): Within a single-quoted string, the double-quote is a regular character, and doesn't act as a quote. Similarly the other way around.

If you want to pass to python the argument `print('$1$2MyString')`, you can do the necessary escaping, which is made awkward by the fact that the string contains both single quotes and dollar signs, meaning neither single nor double quotes can be used without further escaping. Even for that string itself, let alone considering the second level of quoting required.

Or, do something like passing the string through the environment to `sh`:

```
code="print('\$1\$2MyString')"  # or
code='print('\''$1$2MyString'\'')'

code=$code sh -c 'exec python -c "$code"'
```

or, if the output was supposed to be `'$1$2MyString'`, with the single quotes, then the Python code needs to be `print("'$1$2MyString'")`:

```
code='print("'\''$1$2MyString'\''")'
code=$code sh -c 'exec python -c "$code"'
```

It might be simpler to just put the Python code in a file.